# Save current date and time in Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, simpledateformat

First of all I read many posts about Date and found out how to get Date and customize it. But my problem is that I need current date for every time I press button. To be more clear:

```
DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy, h:mm");
String dateFormat = date.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

And after that I'm calling my Model class to setDate `gramHelp.setDate(dateFormat);` 
That works fine but when I check list of dates in my SQL database I only get current date and time for this moment and not for moment when I saved the date. The same problem is in my another activity where I'm calling `getDate()` to list all dates in database.

```
DateFormat datum = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy, h:mm");
String date = datum.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
holder.date.setText(date)
```

The code is basically the same, just this time I'm calling `getTime()` and not `setTime()`.

For example, this is the list of dates:

[image]

for the moment when I'm writing this post. You can see that I have 5 inputs, but I did that every few minutes. Nevertheless in SQL database and my list this is result.

So how to get (save) date and time exactly when I pressed the button ? I guess the answer is really simple but still didn't manage to find it.

**UPDATE**

In first activity I have FAB that saves date/time in SQL database after click.

```
 public void onClick(View v) {        
            DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy, h:mm");
            String dateFormat = date.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            GramHelp gramHelp = new GramHelp();              
            gramHelp.setDate(dateFormat);
            mDatabase.addGramTotal(gramHelp);
        }
```

`GramHelp`is my model class where I have all constructors and getter() and setter() methods. I am also calling `addGramTotal()` function from my database. This is simple function with `ContentValues` for inserting value in my SQL database.

```
public void addGramTotal(GramHelp gramHelp){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();      
    values.put(FoodEntry.COLUMN_DATE, String.valueOf(gramHelp.getDate()));       
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.update(FoodEntry.TABLE_NAME_HELPER, values, null, null);
}
```

To display all dates/times in SQL database I'm using RecyclerView. In activity with RecyclerView I am calling one more function called `listHistory()`. This function is simple `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY COLUMN_DATE`. That part should be fine.

And also in my Adapter class for RecyclerView inside `onBindViewHolder()` method I have:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(HistoryAdapter.HistoryViewHolder holder, final int position) {               
    DateFormat datum = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy, h:mm");
    String date = datum.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    holder.date.setText(date);     
}
```

**SECOND UPDATE:**

So this is of my table where date/time is saved. [image: screenshoot] 
As you can see, time is showing only newest insert.
This is my whole `SELECT` code from my database. You can see that I am saving more values in this table. Also I set date as `String` because I couldn't get `Date` for some reason (in RecyclerView Adapter method `onBindViewHolder`). It works with `String`.

But problem shouldn't be with retrieving date/time. Because date/time is changed (updated) every time when I insert new value into table.

Also this is [library](https://github.com/infinum/android_dbinspector) I use to inspect my database.

```
public List<GramHelp> listHistory(){
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " +FoodEntry.TABLE_NAME_HELPER + " ORDER BY " +FoodEntry.COLUMN_DATE + " ASC ";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    List<GramHelp> listDate = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            int id = (cursor.getInt(0));
            int id_food = (cursor.getInt(1));
            int id_menu = (cursor.getInt(2));
            double gram = cursor.getDouble(3);
            double gram_total = cursor.getDouble(4);
            String date = new String(cursor.getString(5));
            listDate.add(new GramHelp(id, id_food, id_menu, gram, gram_total, date));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    return listDate;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, I would expect your code to look more like this:

```
DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy, h:mm");
String dateFormatted = date.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
gramHelp.setDate(dateFormatted);
```

And reading to look like:

```
//DateFormat datum = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy, h:mm");
//String date = datum.format(gramHelp.getDate());
holder.date.setText(gramHelp.getDate())
```

Where gramHelp is a Model. Otherwise `Calendar.getInstance().getTime()` is reading the current time again.

**Edit:**

Now you've added additional info I can see you are calling `db.update` with no id. This will result in no rows being updated (if you read the return value you should see 0)

You have two approaches:

1. If you are only ever supposed to have 1 item in the table (I can't imagine this is the case) or if the insert happens earlier, then when you do the `insert` read the return value which is the row id, use the id on future updates.

   - `int id = db.insert`
   - `db.update(..., ..., "WHERE " + FoodEntry.ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id) } )`
2. If it should create a new row for each item, then replace `db.update` with `db.insert`

   - If you are using this 2nd approach you need to make sure that when you read the data back, you read the correct row by ID or by using ordering `FoodEntry.COLUMN_DATE + " asc"`

For debugging database stuff I really recommend [Stetho](https://github.com/facebook/stetho) by Facebook. Add it to your project with a single line and you can view all the contents of your database from Google Chrome on your computer. (So you know what's in your database and can work out if the data is wrong (from writing) or your query is wrong (for reading)

Comment: With your and @Arjun Solanki examples I still get same result. First saved date/time is ok, but when I insert second value, the first date/time will update and will show same date/time value like the newest insered data.

Comment: Then you need to show some actual code where you insert and select the date

Comment: I should said that I'm using `db.update` because in other activity I already have `db.insert`. If I add insert into `addGramTotal()` function I would save data in new row, and column `COLUMN_DATE` will be empty. So I would have 2 rows for one input.

Comment: so then you need to keep track of the inserted id (method 1)

Comment: Your solution is really good, but still I get same result in my database. I tried with insert and with update. With insert I would just have extra row, but still `COLUMN_DATE` shows only latest result.

Comment: Ok, do two things. Inspect with Stetho (i'm about to add to my answer), then you can see what ends up in db so you know if the problem is insert or select. Then also post your select code

Comment: After some time I realized that Stetho lib is similar to DBInspector lib that I am using on Android device. I will edit my post for `SELECT ` part and screenshoot.

Answer (score -1):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int date = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
    int month2 = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int month = month2 + 1;
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Above code is simple for get a current date and time.